# jQuery: Blur function is not calling on each dynamically added row

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am newbie to jQuery.I am trying to call the Blur function on each dynamically Added row and send the values of each row of both text box to PHP.
For first row, it works but dynamically added rows, its not working.
My Code is as follows:
   HTML and Jquery:

```
 <!doctype HTML>
    <html>
    <head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var rowCount = 1;
    function addMoreRows(frm) {
    rowCount ++;
    var recRow = '<p id="rowCount'+rowCount+'"><tr><td><input name="" type="text" id="co_name" size="17%"  maxlength="120" /></td><td><input name="" type="text"  id="co_qty" maxlength="120" style="margin: 4px 5px 0 5px;"/></td></tr> <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="removeRow('+rowCount+');">Delete</a></p>';
    jQuery('#addedRows').append(recRow);
    }

    function removeRow(removeNum) {
    jQuery('#rowCount'+removeNum).remove();
    }
    </script>
    <body>
    <table rules="all" style="background:#fff;">
    <tr>
    <td style="font-size:14px;" >Name</td>
    <td style="font-size:14px;" >Email</td>

    <td><span style="font:normal 12px agency, arial; color:blue; text-decoration:underline; cursor:pointer;" onclick="addMoreRows(this.form);">
    Add More
    </span>
    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="rowId">
    <td><input name="" type="text"  id="co_name" value="" size="17%"/></td>
    <td><input name="" type="text" id="co_qty" value="" /></td>

    </table>
    <div id="addedRows"></div>
    </td>
    </tr>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#co_qty').on('blur',function () {
    var username = $('#co_name').val(); 
     var password = $('#co_qty').val(); 
    $.ajax({
             type: "POST",
             url: "blur.php",
             data: {'title':username ,'title1':password},
             success: function(msg) {
      alert(msg)             }

    }); 
     });
    });

    </script>
    </body>
    </html><br>
```

blur.php

```
$var=$_POST['title'];
$var1=$_POST['title1'];
echo $var."Success!".$var1;
```

I am not getting it. Please do suggest me.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Use `on()` to bind dynamically added elements on DOM.

Because when DOM is ready, it doesn't have those elements and when you add those dynamically, DOM doesn't understand those.

```
$('body').on('blur','.co_qty', function () {
   //Your code
});
```

And I can see that you've multiple elements (text-box) with same id `#co_qty`, it cause problems.

You need to use `.co_qty` to apply on dynamically added elements.

Comment: Thanks.But it only shows the value of first row in each dynamically rows called.

Comment: You need to add the dynamic selector to each element which is added dynamically.